# can I implement the push notifications without enrolling in the developer program?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push, iphone-developer-program

I'm quit new in iphone developing and I used to test my apps on my jailbreaken iPhone 3Gs without enrolling in the developer program.
However, I needed to implement push notifications from my server but all the tutorials I found refer to logging in the provisioning portal to obtain App ID which I can't access without the developer program.

So here is the question: Can I implement the push notifications without enrolling in the developer program ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the required certificates and profiles for your server need to be generated by Apple, so you can't forge them.

Answer (score 0):

No, you wont be able to do that kind of communication while your app is closed. It will work only when the user is running your app thus making it useless.

Comment: huh? your app can be closed and still receive push notifications. That is the whole point of push notifications.

Comment: But he specified without enrolling in the developer program, I am aware that is the main purpose for them but without the apple backend to send them you cant.